# Spring Cloud Config Server excample - overrides in application config

Tags: spring-cloud

I try to setup a spring cloud config server and started with the example provided on github.
https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples/configserver

However I am a bit confused by the application.yml (https://github.com/spring-cloud-samples/configserver/blob/master/src/main/resources/application.yml) configuration file. It is about the overrides part for profile 'latice'

```
spring:
  profiles: lattice
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        overrides:
          eureka:
            client:
              serviceUrl:
                defaultZone: ${EUREKA_SERVICE_URL:http://localhost:8761}/eureka/
            instance:
              hostname: $\{CF_INSTANCE_IP:localhost}
              nonSecurePort: $\{CF_INSTANCE_PORT:$\{PORT:$\{server.port:8080}}}      
eureka:
  instance:
    hostname: ${CF_INSTANCE_IP:localhost}
    nonSecurePort: ${CF_INSTANCE_PORT:${PORT:${server.port:8888}}}
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: ${EUREKA_SERVICE_URL:http://localhost:8761}/eureka/
```

Why is the overrides needed? Basically it is the same as defined in the eureka settings below.
I also did not find anything regarding the overrides in the documentation.

Thanks a lot for your help

Cheers 
Florian

Comment: Good question, at a glance nothing appears in the documentation about the overrides property.  Looking at the source it appears it is a way to override a clients settings. Per code comments: `Extra map for a property source to be sent to all clients unconditionally`

Answer (score 0):

It's not quite the same as the configuration below it. For one thing the config server doesn't send its own configuration to clients (except the overrides). For another, notice the escapes (`\`) to prevent placeholder resolution before sending to the client. This means that the client's eureka hostname (for instance) is constructed using its own value of `CF_INSTANCE_IP` not the server's.

Comment: So the escaping I have seen before.

But which client eureka client configuration does it override? Its own or of the clients connected to the cloud config server?

Basically I would assume that the second option (config server client) is the case because otherwise I do not really get why this is needed.

Comment: It ends up getting used by the client, so the latter, I guess.